# Python regex compile match in multiline

Tags: python-3.x

Multiline regex search to build a list

i have tried to use re.compile with specific pattern along with flag re.MULTILINE however its not working.

```py
rx_dict = {
    'user_db_pppoe' : re.compile(r"sap-session-limit\s\d{5}\n\s+(?P<USERDB_P>.*)\w+")
}

with open('test_input.txt', 'r') as file_object:
    if key == 'user_db_pppoe':
        print(match)
```

Configuration:

```py
                    pppoe
                        policy "pppoe-change-mtu"
                        session-limit 32767
                        sap-session-limit 32767
                        user-db "LAC-l2tp-DXB"
                        no shutdown
                    exit
                exit
```

however multiline is not accepting with re module

```py
rx_dict = {
    'user_db_pppoe' : re.compile(r"sap-session-limit\s\d{5}\n\s+(?P<USERDB_P>.*)\w+" , re.MULTILINE)}
```

my requirement to match user-db value here "LAC-l2tp-DXB" which is following sap-session-limit value.

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with your code, here a commented way to do it (assuming that "Configuration" in your question is `test_input.txt` content:

```py
### specify both substring you want to find in the line
rx_dict = {
    'user_db' : re.compile(r"LAC-l2tp-DXB"),
    'sap_session_limit' : re.compile(r"sap-session-limit")
}

### open the file
with open('test_input.txt', 'r') as file_object:
    ### start a counter to remember line number
    line_count = 0
    ### open loop over the file line (you have to use string for regex, nt as you did in example on file_object)
    for line in file_object :
        ### if found first ocurrence remember line number of first match
        if (rx_dict['sap_session_limit'].search(line)) :
            sap_line = line_count
        ### if found second one AND the line is the next to first ocurrence find
        if (rx_dict['user_db'].search(line) and line_count == (sap_line + 1)) :
            ### ... do what you want to do ...
            print(line)            
        ### increase counter
        line_count += 1
```

this does what you asked for. Please also note that you used a bad dictionary key reference, have a look at [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) for the right use of key and values.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. The above proposed code will look for specific values and match a line. However my requirement to capture values configured under each hierarchy which is called group interface. User-db field will have variable values which needs to be captured. However this user-db appears under two different subsection. Config will follows as . “Dhcp\n user-db “valueA” “

Comment: this is what you said you need (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)